Makefile won't build, fatal error cannot specify with multiple files
I'm not that related in the C/C++ programming there's a library I wanted to try out needed to be compile using CMake so I built it with MinGW Makefiles generator with the last Boost library it succeeded but when I wish to build my Makefile using the mingw32-make I always get this error :
[  3%] Building C object geogram/src/lib/geogram/third_party/CMakeFiles/geogram_third_party.dir/LM7/libmeshb7.c.obj
cc.exe: fatal error: cannot specify '-o' with '-c', '-S' or '-E' with multiple files
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make[2]: *** [geogram\src\lib\geogram\third_party\CMakeFiles\geogram_third_party.dir\build.make:76: geogram/src/lib/geogram/third_party/CMakeFiles/geogram_third_party.dir/LM7/libmeshb7.c.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1092: geogram/src/lib/geogram/third_party/CMakeFiles/geogram_third_party.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:167: all] Error 2

I searched everywhere but didn't found a solution to my problem, does anybody have a solution ?
For informations I'm trying to build the TetWild library and I used :
CMake 3.28.1
Boost Library 1.86.0
Edit: I used the given method to build the project by changing some things for compatibility on WindowsOS, basically i did:
git https://github.com/Yixin-Hu/TetWild.git
cd TetWild
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
mingw32-make

And then I have the error.
(I also added the Path to my Boost Library to the Boost Root in the CMakeList file before the cmake command since I didn't used the deafault location to compile my Boost build)
Edit2: This is the autogenerated Makefile by CMake
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "MinGW Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.28

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all
.PHONY : default_target

# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:

#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : %,v

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : RCS/%

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : RCS/%,v

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : SCCS/s.%

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : s.%

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list

# Command-line flag to silence nested $(MAKE).
$(VERBOSE)MAKESILENT = -s

#Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:

# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:
.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

SHELL = cmd.exe

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"

# The command to remove a file.
RM = "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E rm -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = "C:\Users\BudwaelBiais\Documents\00 - GIT\TetSphere\TetWild"

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = "C:\Users\BudwaelBiais\Documents\00 - GIT\TetSphere\TetWild\build"

Edit3: First thanks for the reply, so for the CMakeLists File dince I installed my Boost Library to a different location that the usual I added some line codes aswell as the precision on the boost library architecture since it couldn't find the lib files without:
set(BOOST_ROOT to/my/boost/location)
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR to/my/boost/location/include)
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR to/my/boost/location/lib)
set(Boost_ARCHITECTURE "-x64")
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)

and for the verbose from the make files I got the following:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f geogram\src\lib\geogram\third_party\CMakeFiles\geogram_third_party.dir\build.make geogram/src/lib/geogram/third_party/CMakeFiles/geogram_third_party.dir/depend
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/BudwaelBiais/Documents/00 - GIT/TetSphere/TetWild/build'
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" "C:\Users\BudwaelBiais\Documents\00 - GIT\TetSphere\TetWild" "C:\Users\BudwaelBiais\Documents\00 - GIT\TetSphere\TetWild\extern\geogram\src\lib\geogram\third_party" "C:\Users\BudwaelBiais\Documents\00 - GIT\TetSphere\TetWild\build" "C:\Users\BudwaelBiais\Documents\00 - GIT\TetSphere\TetWild\build\geogram\src\lib\geogram\third_party" "C:\Users\BudwaelBiais\Documents\00 - GIT\TetSphere\TetWild\build\geogram\src\lib\geogram\third_party\CMakeFiles\geogram_third_party.dir\DependInfo.cmake" "--color="
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/BudwaelBiais/Documents/00 - GIT/TetSphere/TetWild/build'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f geogram\src\lib\geogram\third_party\CMakeFiles\geogram_third_party.dir\build.make geogram/src/lib/geogram/third_party/CMakeFiles/geogram_third_party.dir/build
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/BudwaelBiais/Documents/00 - GIT/TetSphere/TetWild/build'
[  3%] Building C object geogram/src/lib/geogram/third_party/CMakeFiles/geogram_third_party.dir/LM7/libmeshb7.c.obj
cd /d C:\Users\BUDWAE~1\DOCUME~1\00-GIT~1\TETSPH~1\TetWild\build\geogram\src\lib\geogram\THIRD_~1 && C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\cc.exe -DNOMINMAX -DVC_EXTRALEAN -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES @CMakeFiles/geogram_third_party.dir/includes_C.rsp -fdiagnostics-color=always -O3 -DNDEBUG /D_SECURE_SCL=0 /GS- /Ox   -fdiagnostics-color=always /nologo /MP  /wd4275 /wd4996 /wd4512 /bigobj /W3 /wd4245 /wd4389 -MD -MT geogram/src/lib/geogram/third_party/CMakeFiles/geogram_third_party.dir/LM7/libmeshb7.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\geogram_third_party.dir\LM7\libmeshb7.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\geogram_third_party.dir\LM7\libmeshb7.c.obj -c "C:\Users\BudwaelBiais\Documents\00 - GIT\TetSphere\TetWild\extern\geogram\src\lib\geogram\third_party\LM7\libmeshb7.c"
cc.exe: fatal error: cannot specify '-o' with '-c', '-S' or '-E' with multiple files
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make[2]: *** [geogram\src\lib\geogram\third_party\CMakeFiles\geogram_third_party.dir\build.make:76: geogram/src/lib/geogram/third_party/CMakeFiles/geogram_third_party.dir/LM7/libmeshb7.c.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/BudwaelBiais/Documents/00 - GIT/TetSphere/TetWild/build'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1092: geogram/src/lib/geogram/third_party/CMakeFiles/geogram_third_party.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/BudwaelBiais/Documents/00 - GIT/TetSphere/TetWild/build'
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:165: all] Error 2


Please show all the steps you did to download, setup, and build the project.

Run mingw32-make with additional option VERBOSE=1. That way it will print exact command lines which are used for compiling (and linking).

The error occurs in geogram\src\lib\geogram\third_party\CMakeFiles\geogram_third_party.dir\build.make, so you should check this file. Run mingw32-make VERBOSE=1 to get the commands printed. The command that results in the error message might help to find the corresponding rule in ...\build.make.

The makefile generated by cmake is irrelevant.  The only way it would matter is if you are suspecting there's a bug in CMake.  Otherwise the makefile is just an intermediate form; it's like having a compiler error and posting the assembly code that the compiler generates.  What matters here is the content of the CMakeFile not the makefile.

You say you "changed some things for compatibilty".  I'd suggest that those changes are where you start to look for your problem.  What changes did you make?  To me it looks like you added the compiler's -c option to one of the CMake flags variables where it does not belong, such as into the CMAKE_C_FLAGS variable.

Thanks for the repplies I added most of what you suggested

It seems that TetWild project doesn't support MinGW (yet). It translates target system into the variable VORPALINE_PLATFORM by using the following code:
if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Windows")
    set(VORPALINE_ARCH_64 TRUE CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    set(VORPALINE_PLATFORM Win-vs-generic CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
elseif(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")
    set(VORPALINE_PLATFORM Linux64-gcc-dynamic CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
elseif(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Darwin")
    set(VORPALINE_PLATFORM Darwin-clang-dynamic CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
endif()

That is, in case of MinGW generator it selects Win-vs-generic platform for Geogram subproject (which uses the variable VORPALINE_PLATFORM). That platform means Visual Studio compiler, so the subproject adds several VS-specific options, e.g. /D_SECURE_SCL=0. MinGW compiler doesn't have special treatment of such slash-options, so it treats them as filenames. This is why you got the error message.
Possible platforms for geogram subproject includes MinGW-x86_64-w64, so a possible fix for TetWild project could be to set VORPALINE_PLATFORM variable to MinGW-x86_64-w64 in case when MinGW variable is defined.
